# error A member with the name 'token_type' already exists JsonPropertyAttribute

Tags: c#, json, json.net

```
//{"access_token":"myaccesstoken","expires_in":3600,"token_type":"Bearer"}
string responseString = null;
TokenResponse tokenResponse = new TokenResponse();
tokenResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenResponse>(responseString);

public class TokenResponse
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the access token.
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "access_token")]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    ////
    //// Summary:
    ////     Gets the identity token.
    //public string IdentityToken { get; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the type of the token.
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "token_type")]
    public string TokenType { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the refresh token.
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "token_type")]
    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the error description.
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "error_description")]
    public string ErrorDescription { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the expires in.
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "expires_in")]
    public int ExpiresIn { get; set; }
}
```

**Exception error message**

"A member with the name 'token_type' already exists on 'app1.TokenResponse'. Use the JsonPropertyAttribute to specify another name."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have applied the exact attribute (below one) twice,

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "token_type")]
```

on two different properties. Once for `TokenType` and once for `RefreshToken`. Your code copy pasted below:

```
// Summary:
//     Gets the type of the token.
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "token_type")]  //<---
public string TokenType { get; set; }
//
// Summary:
//     Gets the refresh token.
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "token_type")] //<---
public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have one field having two different meanings in different contexts. Typically this would not be a favourable data format since it adds messy logic to the consumer on the other end.they need to divine what the "Json" property should mean in each case.

Maybe you can add them in two different classes :

```
   public class TokenRefresh
   {
    //Gets the type of the token.
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "token_type")]
     public string TokenType { get; set; }
   }
   public class TokenResponse
   { 
    //     Gets the refresh token.
     [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "token_type")]
      public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
   }
```